# no code execution after while- or for-loop in C

Tags: c, xcode8

I’m learning C using Xcode 8 and the compiler doesn’t run any code after a while- or for-loop executes. is this a bug? how can I fix it?

In the example provided below `printf("code executed after while-loop");` never executes

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getTheLine(char string[]);

int getTheLine(char string[]) {

  char character;
  int index;
  index = 0;

  while ((character = getchar()) >= EOF) {

    string[index] = character;
    ++index;
  }

  printf("code executed after while-loop");
  return index;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  char string[100];
  int length = getTheLine(string);
  printf("length %d\n", length);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could start showing us your code.

Comment: The compiler should not *run* any code at all. It should compile [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) into object files which are then linked into an executable. The IDE can then start a process to run the executable.

Comment: More to the point, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question to include code, don't post it as comments. And please make it *complete*, especially with variable declarations (in this case I think that's very important).

Comment: Please note that `getchar()` returns `int`, since `EOF` does not fit in a `char`.

Comment: one should file a bug "xcode/clang does not support for-loop" - no, joke :-)   you probably have an infinite or at least very long running loop. Show your code, please.

Comment: @CristianLăpușan Please don't edit important aspects of the posted code **after** answers have been posted - especially when the answers quotes that specific part of the code. By doing that the answers are invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

`getchar` returns an `int` not a `char`, and comparison with `EOF` should be done with the `!=` operator instead of the `>=` operator.

```
...
int character;   // int instead of char
int index;
index = 0;

while ((character = getchar()) != EOF) {  // != instead of >=
...
```

Comment: I initially wrote the code like you suggested. same problem

Comment: @CristianLăpușan Your code with my fixes applied works fine here. What exactly is your input? What is your platform? Remember: on Linux EOF is done with Ctrl+D, on Windows it's done with Ctrl+Z.

Comment: I’m using Xcode, macOS Sierra.

Comment: @CristianLăpușan OK; and what keys exactly are you typing?

Comment: the problem was the while-loop never ended! As I have mentioned already I have no experience with C. thank you all for the help provided!

Answer (score 2):

It's the `>= EOF`, which will let the condition be always `true`. The reason is that a "valid" result of `getchar()` will be a positive integer, and a "non-valid" result like end-of-file will be `EOF`, which is negative (cf. [getchar()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)):

> EOF ... integer constant expression of type int and negative value

Hence, any valid result from `getchar` will be `>EOF`, while the end-of-file-result will be `==EOF`, such that `>= EOF` will always match.

Write `!= EOF` instead.

Note further that you do not terminate your string by the string-terminating-character `'\0'`, such that using `string` like a string (e.g. in a `printf("%s",string))` will yield undefined behaviour (crash or something else probably unwanted). 
So write at least:

```
while ((character = getchar()) != EOF) {
    string[index] = character;
    ++index;
}
string[index]='\0';
```

Then there is still the issue that you may write out of bounds, e.g. if one enters more then 100 characters in your example. But checking this is now beyond the actual question, which was about the infinite loop.

Comment: If I exit the function early, say I insert immediately after the loop "if (character == 47) {return index;}", then the code runs fine

Comment: @Cristian Lăpușan: I suppose you mean "inside the loop", because your loop will never end; so "code executed after while-loop" is never printed, right?

Answer (score 2):

The symbolic constant `EOF` is an *integer* constant, of type `int`. It's (usually) defined as a macro as `-1`.

The problem is that the value `-1` as an (32-bit) `int` has the value `0xffffffff` and as a (8-bit) `char` the same value would be `0xff`. Those two values are not equal. Which in turn means that your loop condition will *never* be false, leading to an infinite loop.

The solution to this problem is that all standard functions that reads characters returns them as an `int`. Which means your variable `character` needs to be of that type too.

Important note: It's a compiler implementation detail if plain `char` is a signed or an unsigned type. If it is signed then a comparison to an `int` would lead to *sign extension* when the `char` value is promoted in the comparison. That means a `signed char` with the value `0xff` would be extended to the `int` value `0xffffffff`. That means if `char` is signed then the comparison would work.

This means that your compile have `char` as `unsigned char`. So the `unsigned char` value `0xff` after promotion to `int` will be `0x000000ff`.

---

As for *why* the value `-1` becomes `0xffffffff` is because of how negative numbers are usually represented on computers, with something called [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

---

You also have another couple of flaws in your code.

The first is that since the loop is infinite you will go *way* out of bounds of the `string` array, leading to *undefined behavior* (and a possible crash sooner or later). The solution to this is to add a condition to make sure that `index` never reaches `100` (in the specific case of your array, should really be passed as an argument).

The second problem is that if you intend to use the `string` array as an actual string, you need to *terminate* it. Strings in C are actually called *null **terminated** strings*. That terminator is the character `'\0'` (equal to integer `0`), and need to be put at the end of every string you want to pass to a standard function handling such strings. Having this terminator means that an array of `100` characters only can have 99 characters in it, to be able to fit the terminator. This have implications to the solution to the above problem. As for how to add the terminator, simply do `string[index] = '\0';` after the loop (if `index` is within bounds of course).

Comment: it does not work..

Comment: @CristianLăpușan How does *what* "not work"? Did you change the type of `character` to `int`? Are you doing something else you do not show us? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger? And have you tried adding a (trailing) newline to the string you print after the loop (since output to `stdout` is by default line-buffered)?

Comment: Upvoted for all the details you bring in. But just for me to understand: doesn't integral promotion in `(char)-1 == (int)-1` make sure that `(char)-1` is actually extended to `0xffffffff`?

Comment: @StephanLechner That depends. I should probably add that `char` can be either `signed` *or* `unsigned` (it's up to the compiler) and if it's `signed` then yes there would be sign-extension. Not so when `char` is `unsigned` (which seems to be the case here, or it should work).

Comment: I appreciate your input. thank you very much! the problem is that even code out of learn book does not get executed if a while-loop precedes

Comment: @CristianLăpușan please tell us which keys _exactly_ you press once the program is running, so we can understand why it doesn't work on your computer.

Comment: @CristianLăpușan If you still can't make it work after changing the type and added the newline when printing, then please post a new question (with the *updated* code) about it.

Comment: found the solution. command + D + D (command followed by double pressing D) to signal EndOfFile. very easy! the while-loop exited and code after the loop got executed as well. I kept character variable of type char. it didn’t matter if I chose int or char. thank you for all of your input!